# What does it mean that an appliance has a power of 170W?

Tags: arduino, voltage, power, solar-charge-controller

I would like to drive an appliance of 170W and 12V with a 12V 3W solar panel using an arduino nano. Given the a difference in the power of these 2 devices (170W and 3W), I don't know if this is feasible.

What does it mean that an appliance has a power of 170W? is it possible to add up several 12V solar panels to match up this power, or a single 12V solar panel is enough?

Comment: It means you need at least fifty seven 3W solar panels to reach the required 170W. We don't know what solar panels or solar controller you have to answer if 57 panels can be added somehow together.

Comment: Electrical power is pretty much what the English word means.  170 W is a bit under what a good amateur cyclist produces.  3 W is about a [hummingbird during hover](https://escholarship.org/content/qt3c62v99s/qt3c62v99s_noSplash_734065127b3a083f60d7887a14da2d1a.pdf?t=mtfbk2).  You can see it would take a lot of hummingbirds to win a tug of war against a cyclist.

Comment: @jonathanjo very good intuitive explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I leave it to others to describe watts, volts and amps, and the fact that things have sizes, and that if you have $3 you will not be successfully buying a $170 thing.

I want to address the idea that a solar panel can run a load directly.  Just to set your expectations...  Not really.

The solar panel rating is the absolute maximum in perfect conditions - you are unlikely to be in those conditions unless it's noon at the equator on the clearest day of the year, and your load just happens to be just the right voltage to hit MPPT for that condition.  So realistically you can expect between 50-70% of rating at best conditions, and often as little as 10% e.g. overcast late afternoon.

And this can change dramatically moment by moment as a cloud (or plane) flies over.

So the upshot is it's *impractical* to rely on solar as your only power source.  Even if the panel capacity is 2x the load, it will randomly be cutting out on you all the time unless you monstrously oversize the panels (e.g. 10x) which is a waste of money and space.

### The cure for this is batteries.

We're really good at having solar panel charge controllers that charge a battery in all solar conditions.  That's just commercial off the shelf stuff you can buy easily.

If the solar is delivering too little to run the load, the battery can cover the deficit for awhile. So the load remains stable despite clouds messing with panel output.

And something like an Arduino can monitor battery state of charge to make sure the battery isn't drained flat.

For instance if you have a cyclical load like a dehumidifier or air conditioner, you can cycle it on when battery is near top of charge and cycle it off when battery reaches a low cutoff (70% for lead-acid or 20% for lithium). This means you don't need a particularly large battery, nor a particularly large solar system.

For instance at extremes, consider a power operated driveway gate.  It might need 170 watts *for the 5 seconds it runs*, but it only runs 8 times a day, so a 3 watt solar panel might be more than enough to keep its battery topped up.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the 170W from a nameplate, that may be a maximum. The appliance may draw significantly less than that during operation, but it will still generally be in that ballpark. So let's use 170W.

The "3W" may be a bit (or more) optimistic- optimal mid-day conditions. Even if honestly rated, a full 24-hour day under favorable conditions will result in maybe equivalent 4 hours of light (typical ratio for home solar systems), so let's be optimistic and say 12 Wh of energy. If there is no energy loss whatsoever in conversion and storage of energy then a single '3W' solar cell for a day charging batteries would operate the appliance for several minutes.

More likely you'd lose enough energy in storage and conversion that you'd be lucky to get 60 seconds operation for a full day charging.

Answer (score 0):

The power rating of an appliance is how much power it might dissipate at max. This doesn't give you the whole story. It might not be able to operate on "any power source". For instance, your appliance will have a rated operation voltage that you must comply. If not, It won't be operational.  It also doesn't tell you the required source impedance (but that's a bit more complex). If you want to power your appliance, (let say they are both 12V), you will need an accumulator (battery). Also, your average power consumption should be in average to the average power delivery of your solar panel.

Let's say you have a 30W light you want to use during the night. Your solar panel generate 3W during 10h. You get a capacity of 30W/h. Therefore, your light would run for around 1h (in a no loss world!). Therefore, a 170W appliance could run about 10 minutes a day with such a small solar panel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the appliance runs on 120V AC, it means that you would need to supply 170/120, or 1.4 amps and 120V AC, to the appliance.  Your solar panel will be unable to keep up  As mentioned in comments, you would need many of these solar panels to do this.

Two other options come to mind.  You can create a system where your 3W panel charges many batteries, and then you can use an inverter system to generate the necessary voltage at the required current. Another option would be to run your nano off the solar panel, plug the appliance into the wall, and use a relay turned on and off with the nano to control the appliance.